# Xen keeps making the time wrong on a Windows guest

Tags: 12.04, time, xen

Just upgraded our Ubuntu Server to 12.04.1 LTS. It runs a Xen VM, which is Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

We are using the `xl` toolchain for Xen.

We are in the UK, which is currently GMT+1 (BST).

The time is correct on the host, i.e. it knows we're in BST.

```
tf@hostname:~$ date
Mon Oct  1 12:16:45 BST 2012
```

The time on the Windows guest keeps getting reset to GMT, i.e. 1 hour behind where it should be.

We had this on the previous Ubuntu release using the `xm` toolchain, which was fixed with the option `localtime=1`, however `xl` seems to ignore the `localtime` option.

I cannot find a mechanism to either:

- get Xen to pass local time through to the guests with the `xl` toolchain

or

- get Xen to leave the guest clock alone and allow NTP on the guest to keep things in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/Time-is-off-by-an-hour-in-my-XEN-vm-tp2586195p2586196.html

There is a RealTimeIsUniversal registry flag hidden in the windows registry that can be set (its not in by default) to let Windows interpret the RTC as UTC as well.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation] "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001`